# How to get the whole row with column names while looking for a minimum value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame. There are four columns.

[image]

**I can find a minimum number using this code:**

```
df_temp=df_A2C.loc[ (df_A2C['TO_ID'] == 7)]

mini_value = df_temp['DURATION_H'].min()
print("minimum value in column 'TO_ID' is: " , mini_value)
```

**Output:**

```
minimum value in column 'TO_ID' is:  0.434833333333333
```

Now, I am trying to get the whole row with all column names while looking for a minimum value using `TO_ID`. Something like this.

[image]

**How can we get the whole row with all column names while looking for a minimum value?**

Comment: [Series.argmin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.argmin.html) returns the "int position of the smallest value in the Series". You can get the position with that and then use that position in `.iloc` to get the full row

Comment: `df_A2C.iloc[df_A2C['TO_ID'].argmin()]`

Comment: `df_temp.loc[df_temp['DURATION_H'].min(), :]` or `df_A2C.loc[ (df_A2C['TO_ID'] == 7 & df_A2C['TO_ID'].min()), :]`

Comment: @Naveed Indeed it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you post the data as a code or text, I would have been able to share the result

assumption: you're searching for a minimum value for a specific to_id

```
# as per your code, filter out by to_id
# sort the result on duration and take the top value

df_A2C.loc[ (df_A2C['TO_ID'] == 7)].sort_values('DURATION_H').head(1)
```

Comment: Hi again. I have posted another question related to the same data. If possible, please have a look. This is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130926/getting-empty-data-frames-but-there-is-no-empty-or-null-values-in-in-my-data

Comment: @Naveed Following this  `df_A2C.loc[ (df_A2C['TO_ID'] == 7)].sort_values('DURATION_H').head(1)`. When reading the data from an excel file, it discards values after the decimal point. I can post a question in case you need a specific example.

Comment: @LearningLogic, yes please post a separate question. Thanks!

Comment: @Naveed Here it is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74145501/getting-exact-value-in-decimal-in-data-frames/74145545#74145545

Comment: @Naveed Is it possible to control column name repetition? The column names are coming as duplicates in each iteration.

Comment: @Oceans Just use `df_A2C.loc[(df_A2C['TO_ID'] == i)].sort_values('DURATION_H').head(1).values`