# getting empty data frames but there is no empty or NULL Values in my data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

My data looks like this:

[image]

I have `648258` samples in total. The `FROM_ID` has `43 values`, and `TO_ID has 648258 values`. I am finding the `minimum value` against each `TO_ID`.

**Here is a sample code:**

```
for i in range(1, len(df), 1):
    A2C_TT= df_A2C.loc[(df_A2C['TO_ID'] == i)].sort_values('DURATION_H').head(1)
    print (A2C_TT)
```

**Output:**

[image]

However, I have `no NULL` or `empty data frames` in my data.

**What can be a possible reason, and how to handle it?**

Comment: does your data have a `TO_ID` value of 33 and 39? those appear to be the ones missing.

Comment: @scotscotmcc I just checked it. I have no TO_ID =33 or 39. It is showing nan. How should I iterate my loop in this case?

Answer (score 0):

groupby to_id, take the minimum of Duration_h

```
df.groupby('TO_ID')['DURATION_H'].min()
```

Comment: I got a hint. Actually, I am iterating the for loop in series 1 to so on. However, I have no TO_ID =33 or 39. That's why I am getting empty data frames. How should I iterate my loop to avoid these empty data frame?

Comment: for loop is an anti-pattern, so should be avoided when working with pandas. to your question, *if A2C_TT.size > 0: print A2C_TT*

Comment: size gives you the number of rows.  furthermore. you can make use of iterrows when looping through the DF,   https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html?highlight=iterrows#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows

Comment: Thanks. How `df.groupby('TO_ID')['DURATION_H'].min()` can play a role here? I did not get it.

Comment: it groups by TO_ID and return the min DURATION_H for each of the groups

Comment: Following your code, I am not able to get column names. Also, I need the whole row with all column names. However this works : `for i in range(1, 44, 1):
    A2C_TT= df_A2C.loc[(df_A2C['TO_ID'] == i)].sort_values('DURATION_H').head(1)
    if A2C_TT.size > 0:
        print (A2C_TT)`. As you already mentioned, this is not a good approach. I have gone through `iterrows` documentation but could use it since I have multiple columns. **Do you know how I can use `iterrows` while having multiple columns?** specifically in my code.

Comment: @Naveed What if I have to compare two columns? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74166775/finding-minimum-value-with-groupby-by-comparing-two-columns