# Getting exact value in decimal in data frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame with a large set of records.

When reading the data from an excel file, it discards values after the decimal point.

**Actual Value Code:**

```
df_temp=df_A2C.loc[ (df_A2C['TO_ID'] == 7)]

mini_value = df_temp['DURATION_H'].min()
print("minimum value in column 'TO_ID' is: " , mini_value)
```

**Correct Output:**
minimum value in column `'TO_ID'` is:  `0.434833333333333`.

**Discarding values code:**

```
df_A2C.loc[ (df_A2C['TO_ID'] == 7)].sort_values('DURATION_H').head(1)
```

**Wrong Output:**

[image]

I need the actual value i-e `0.434833333333333`

**How to get the exact same value here?**

Comment: Can you try `pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.16f}".format`

Answer (score 1):

refer to the [set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html?highlight=set_option#pandas.set_option) document

```
pd.set_option("display.precision", 16)
```

Comment: where to use this statement? My code is `df_A2C.loc[ (df_A2C['TO_ID'] == 7)].sort_values('DURATION_H').head(1)`

Comment: At top of your code below import statement

Comment: @Bhargav I am reading an excel file like using `df_A2C = pd.read_excel(file_loc1, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])`. Where should I use `pd.set_option("display.precision", 16)` ?

Comment: `Line1`: Import pandas as pd  `Line2` :  `pd.set_option("display.precision", 16)` ....followrd by your code

Comment: @Hanna can u pls edit your answer showing where to add...

Comment: @Bhargav This is changing all values e.g a value `25.53808`
 to `25.5380800000000008`.

Comment: @LearningLogic, the value is not lost, jupyter notebook shows few digits, so change display setting helps. Secondly, if you access the value directly, you get all the decimal places. So, the issue is not the code, its just how it get displayed. Hope it helps

Comment: @Naveed Yes. I just cross-checked it. It is just a presentation. The exact value is still there.